# JQuery .text does not appear in browser, only in firebug, does not get POSTed

Tags: jquery, forms, text, firebug, append

i am trying to update a div and a textarea using a submit button...
the div will be used to show to the user what he's doing and the textarea to submit through a form
my code looks like this:

```
$("#newstuff").click(function() {
    if ($("#newdrugname").val() !== "") {
        var newline = "something: " + var1 + ": " + var2 + ", " + var3 + " text " + var4 + " " + var5;
        var tildenewline = "~" + newline;
        $("<li/>").text(tildenewline).prependTo("#displaystuff");
        var updatedlist = $('div#displaystuff').text();​
```

until here it works ok, the problem is below:

```
        $("#submitstuff").text(updatedlist);
     }
});
```

The `#submitstuff`text area does not get filled with text.
Firebug shows that it does. (text appears between the `<textarea></textarea>`
but nothing appears on the broswer and nothing gets posted upon submit...

What could i be missing here? 
I should point out that it does work some times, and then suddenly stop...
I havent figured out what causes it to work/stop...  and it drives me mad
Any ideas/tips would be greatly  apreciated

here's the HTML:

```
<div class="displaystuff" id="displaystuff"></div>
<textarea id="submitstuff" name="submitstuff" class="hidden2"  style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#submitstuff").text(updatedlist); //Yours
```

To change `textarea` value use `.val()`:

```
$("#submitstuff").val(updatedlist);
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> **The `.text()` method cannot be used on form inputs** or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, **use the .val() method**. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Comment: it was as simple as that... i cant belive ive been missing it all day...  
val doesnt work on this tho: ` var updatedlist = $('div#displaystuff').text();`  
should i keep using .text?

Comment: @krasatos. on `<div>` yes! on form elements no!. **:-)**

Comment: .html() gives me the full markup... with li / tds etc... which i dont want
var updatedlist = $('div#displaystuff').text();
it is safe to use the .text() in this case right?

Comment: @krasatos. yes. please read the api for each function to learn more.

Comment: i went through it but as i am new to the whole php/java/html i thought i needed things that have value="" in them, and that .val() didnt work with textarea></textarea